# How to remove duplicate contiguous elements in an array?

Tags: ruby

Given an array such as

```
arr = [1,1,1,2,2,3,4,1,2]
```

I wish to replace each contiguous string of equal elements with a single instance of that element. Here the result would be

```
[1,2,3,4,1,2]
```

The three `1`s are replaced by a single `1` and the two `2`'s are replaced by a single `2`.

How can I do that for an arbitrary array of Ruby objects?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know you can do it with [`chunk_while`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk_while) and [`map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Enumerable.html#method-i-map), but there might be other ways:

```
[1,1,1,2,2,3,4,1,2].chunk_while { |e, f| e == f }.map(&:first)
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2]
```

With `chunk_while` you split the array by chunks whenever the block is evaluated to true, for that the block yields two variables, the "element before" and the "element after", that's to say, for every iteration you're going to get this:

```
[1, 1]
[1, 1]
[1, 2]
[2, 2]
[2, 3]
[3, 4]
[4, 1]
[1, 2]
```

After applying the logic in the proc, it'll chunk the receiver whenever the first and second yielded elements are equal, and you get:

```
[[1, 1, 1], [2, 2], [3], [4], [1], [2]]
```

After that you can map that result to get only one element from each array - there are many ways, but `first` is enough.

The `chunk_while` proc can also be shortened to `(&:==)`, leaving as `[1,1,1,2,2,3,4,1,2].chunk_while(&:==).map(&:first)`.

Similarly and just out of curiosity, you can use `slice_when` and `last` to save 2 characters: `[1,1,1,2,2,3,4,1,2].slice_when(&:!=).map(&:last)`.

Comment: Its to complicated for me. Can you explain how do you teach ruby? Books, courses, something?

Comment: The [documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk_while) my friend.

Comment: I keep forgetting about `itself`. Nice one @CarySwoveland.

Answer (score -1):

```
arr = [1,1,1,2,2,3,4,1,2]

arr.each do |i|
    (0..arr.length()).each do |j|
        if arr[j] == arr[j+1]
            arr.delete_at(j)
            break
        end
    end
end

print arr
```

What is happening here is the entire list is being traversed; matching consecutive elements in each iteration.

Everytime a match is found, delete it and move on to the next iteration (break). 
In effect, you will be changing the length of the array in each iteration. hence the *break* to avoid index errors.

The nested looping is added to handle any no. of consecutive duplicates.

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the questions. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Thanks for the input.  have added a brief explanation now.

Answer (score -1):

You can use recursive functions to solve this type problems.
I tried different tests. It works.

```
mylist = [1,1,1,2,2,3,4,1,2] #Output:[1,2,3,4,1,2]
mylist2 = [1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,5,5,5,4,1,2] # Output:[1,2,3,5,4,1,2]
mylist3 = [-1,-1,-2,3,5,5,5,4,3,8,8,8,9,6,0,0,6,5] # Output: [-1,-2,3,5,4,3,8,9,6,0,6,5]

def myfunc(mylist)
    mylist.each_with_index do |val, index|
        if val == mylist[index+1]
            mylist.delete_at(index+1)
            myfunc(mylist) # here we call same function again
        end
    end
    return mylist
end

print myfunc(mylist)
puts
print myfunc(mylist2)
puts
print myfunc(mylist3)
```